# Subscribing to changes to @Published

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I am trying to bind the value of `query` to a search box sitting in a `SwiftUI` view.

```
class DataSet: ObservedObject {

... 

@Published var query: String = ""

init() {
    let sub = AnySubscriber<String, Never>(
        receiveSubscription: nil,
        receiveValue: { query in
            print(query)
            return .unlimited
        })
    self.$query.subscribe(sub)
}

...
}
```

When the user changes the value of the `query` I'd like to filter some other property in my `ObservedObject`. Yet I cannot find anywhere in the documentation how do I subscribe to changes to `query` property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use the following approach

```
class DataSet: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var query: String = ""
    
    private var subscribers = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    init() {
        self.$query
            .sink { newQuery in
                    // do something here with newQuery
            }
            .store(in: &subscribers)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! And here's the explanation: subscriptions are cancelled the moment they get out of scope. Therefore if we don't store sink subscription, it will disappear at the end of init().